# Camel - not able to retrieve originalinmessage from unitofwork when using ".aggregate" in route

Tags: apache-camel

In my camel route, I am able to get the original message using

```
exchange.getUnitOfWork().getOriginalInMessage()
```

But once I call aggregate with custom aggregation strategy ,the unit-of-work is null , and I am not able to retrieve the original in message in error handler.

Answer (score 0):

When you aggregate you build a new exchange/message, and there is no original message anymore.

The output from the aggregator EIP is a new Exchange with its own UnitOfWork.

It may be that Camel may not set the output from the aggregator EIP as the original message and it would be `null`. If that is the case we could consider setting the original in message to what the aggregator starts with as output.

Comment: Thanks Claus Ibsen for the confirmation on the aggregate behavior. I used exchange.setProperty to store the original message in the exchange. The exchange property is available in aggregate new exchange as well.

Comment: Yeah whatever you store prior to aggregate you can access as part of aggregation.